# How to use 'And' filter on get_cost_and_usage AWS boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, cloud, boto3

I'm trying to get values based on Dimensions and tags from costexplorer client using get_cost_and_usage, but I keep getting errors for bad formats.

Client: CostExplorer
Filters: Tags and Dimensions

My actual Filter block looks like:

```
And: [{
Dimensions: 'Key': 'USAGE_TYPE',
         'Values': [
            'EU-EBS:VolumeUsage.gp2',
            'EU-EBS:VolumeUsage.gp3',
            'EU-EBS:VolumeUsage.st1'
         ],
Tags: {
'Key': 'tag',
'Values': ['example']
}
}]
```

Comment: with trial and error approach, is it working with only "Dimensions" alone and excluding Tags or vice versa?

Comment: When using Dimensions or Tags alone it works